# How do I add things to the /info endpoint in spring boot programmatically?

Tags: spring-boot

How do I add things to the `/info` endpoint in [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) programmatically? The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-endpoints) states that this is possible for the `/health` endpoint through the use of `HealthIndicator` interface. Is there something for the `/info` endpoint as well?

I would like to add operating system name and version and other runtime info there.

Comment: Although it's not the answer you are looking for, the OS info along with a ton of other runtime info are present in the `/env` mapping

Comment: To add to my previous comment, if you put properties in application.properties like `info.os = ${os.name}` the expression **will** be evaluated and show up correctly in the info endpoint.

Comment: I found this link very helpful: http://mrhaki.blogspot.ie/2016/12/spring-sweets-add-extra-build.html. No custom logic, just few lines of configuration.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Spring Boot 1.4, you are able to declare `InfoContributer` beans to make this a whole lot easier:

```
@Component
public class ExampleInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        builder.withDetail("example",
                Collections.singletonMap("key", "value"));
    }

}
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-custom for more info.

Comment: This should be the answer. The accepted answer is deprecated in Spring now.

Comment: How to make it work with health contributor! the HealthContributor interface is empty!

Comment: still works with latest spring version thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer actually clobbers the InfoEndpoint and does not add to it.

One way I found to *add* to the info is, in a `@Configuration` class, add an `@Autowired` method that adds extra properties following the `info.*` conventions to the environment. Then `InfoEndpoint` will pick them up when its invoked.

You can do something like the following:

```
@Autowired
public void setInfoProperties(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
    /* These properties will show up in the Spring Boot Actuator /info endpoint */
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("info.timeZone", ZoneId.systemDefault().toString());

    env.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("extra-info-props", props));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but this didn't work for me, these additional properties are visible on /env but not on /info. Also I noticed you are putting the time zone there, I am also resetting my default time zones, but found that this code that put them in the properties was called before I reset them.

Comment: Are you sure you prefixed them with "info." as described here? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-application-info . Also, since Properties can take an Object as a value, you can set it as an instance of class that overrides toString() to provide whatever dynamic information you want

Comment: only this one worked for me! wasnt able to get the accepted answer working

Answer (score 9):

One way to do what you want (in the event that you have totally custom properties you need to display) is to declare a bean of type InfoEndpoint which will override the default.

```
@Bean
public InfoEndpoint infoEndpoint() {
     final LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
     map.put("test", "value"); //put whatever other values you need here
     return new InfoEndpoint(map);
}
```

As you can see from the code above, the map can contain whatever info you need.

In the event that the data you want to show can be retrieved by the environment and is not custom, you do not need to override the `InfoEndpoint` bean, but you can simply add properties to the properties file with a prefix of `info`. One example where the OS name is evaluated is the following:

```
info.os = ${os.name}
```

In the code above, Spring Boot will evaluate the right-hand expression before returning the property in the `/info` endpoint.

A final note is that there is a ton of environment information that is already available in the `/env` endpoint

**Update**

As pointed out by @shabinjo, in newer Spring Boot versions there is no `InfoEndpoint` constructor that accepts a map.
You can however use the following snippet:

```
@Bean
public InfoEndpoint infoEndpoint() {
     final Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
     map.put("test", "value"); //put whatever other values you need here
     return new InfoEndpoint(new MapInfoContributor(map));
}
```

The code above will completely override the default info that would end-up in `/info`.
To overcome this issue one could add the following bean

```
@Bean
public MapInfoContributor mapInfoContributor() {
    return new MapInfoContributor(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("test", "value");
    }});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for these very useful tips. I want to _add_ stuff to the default /info (since that already contains useful info like GIT commit id, Maven version, etc..). Returning my own bean would probably not include the defaults?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe You are correct, if you define your own bean you will effectively be excluding the other information. To see how you can re-enable it, take a look at the source code of ` org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration`

Comment: I checked the source, but I cannot `@Autowire` the `InfoPropertiesConfiguration` class because it is protected. :(

Comment: @WimDeblauwe That's bad... It seems like you will have to duplicate the code if you want the same handling but also to be able to add stuff

Comment: @geoand I faced with strange /info behavior. I have declared info.os = ${os.name} in my properties but sometimes /info and /env shows different values for os.name and info one is wrong. Do you know something about it?

Comment: I don't have any specific insights i'm afraid... What values are being displayed?

Comment: i am using springboot starter 1.5.2,new InfoEndpoint(map) is not accepting map as a constructor parameter instead of InfoEndpoint(List<InfoContributor> infoContributors).However i could make it with new InfoEndpoint (infoContributors(new MapInfoContributor(map)).But it is overriding all other info properties and showing onlythis particular info and /info

Comment: @shabinjo Thanks for pointing this out! I added your code in the updated answer

Comment: @shabinjo I also added a solution that would overcome the issue you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to add a custom PropertySource inside an ApplicationListener to add custom info.* properties to the environment (see this answer for an example: [How to Override Spring-boot application.properties programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072628/how-to-override-spring-boot-application-properties-programmatically/29133241#29133241))