# How can I override Spring Boot application.properties programmatically?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have jdbc property files which I take from external configuration web-service
In spring boot in order to set mysql props it's easy as adding those to application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

How could I override those programticlly in my app?

same goes for Spring-batch props:

```
database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydv
database.username=root
database.password=root
```

Answer (score 90):

You can add additional property sources in a lifecycle listener reacting to ApplicationEnvironmentPrepared event.

Something along the lines of:

```
public class DatabasePropertiesListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getEnvironment();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("spring.datasource.url", "<my value>");
    environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("myProps", props));
  }
}
```

Then register the class in src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=my.package.DatabasePropertiesListener
```

This worked for me, however, you are sort of limited as to what you can do at this point as it's fairly early in the application startup phase, you'd have to find a way to get the values you need without relying on other spring beans etc.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. If it helps anybody, you can fetch existing properties from application.properties by using 'environment.getProperty("<prop-name>")' and use it further in your code. I ended up building dynamic number of hornetqueus by populating spring.hornetq.embedded.queues property from an integer defined in my properties file.

Comment: I assume this can also work if I listen for a custom event that I trigger at runtime, and read the properties from the database?

Comment: Only this one worked for me, thanks! One more to mention is that if someone is going to add this listener via java code inside of configurations, he will need to add it in the SpringApplicationBuilder.

Comment: Thanks! this help me when I want to force application run with specific value to a property and ignore the value from properties file.

Answer (score 45):

Just to provide another option to this thread for reference as when I started to look for an answer for my requirement this came high on the search list, but did not cover my use case.

I was looking to programmatically set spring boot property at start up, but without the need to work with the different XML/Config files that spring supports.

The easiest way is to set the properties at the time the SpringApplication is defined. The basic example below sets the tomcat port to 9999.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo40Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Demo40Application.class);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("server.port", 9999);
        application.setDefaultProperties(properties);

        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not override the internal properties, but a good solution to add additional properties

Answer (score 27):

Since spring boot 1.3 [EnvironmentPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/EnvironmentPostProcessor.html) is available for this purpose. Create a subclass of it and register in META-INF/spring.factories A good example is here :

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/48f3f9783f277a795d0210399f0ea09b7f1a4e71/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceEnvironmentPostProcessor.java

Answer (score 17):

If you need to do this for testing purposes: since spring-test 5.2.5 you can use `@DynamicPropertySource`:

```
    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void setDynamicProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("some.property", () -> some.way().of(supplying).a(value) );
    }
```

Takes precedence over pretty much all of the other ways of supplying properties. The method must be static though.

Answer (score 15):

It could be very simple:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(SampleApplication.class)
        .properties(props())
        .build()
        .run(args);
  }

  private static Properties props() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("MY_VAR", "IT WORKS");
    return properties;
  }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
test:
  prop: ${MY_VAR:default_value}
```

Comment: This a cool solution but it doesn't seem to work when there is a conflict with properties in the application.properties.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 13):

As of Spring Boot 2.0.X, you can dynamically override individual properties (for example, in a unit test) using a combination of a custom ApplicationContextInitializer and the ContextConfiguration annotation.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.PortTest.RandomPortInitailizer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils;
import org.springframework.util.SocketUtils;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = RandomPortInitializer.class)
public class PortTest {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(this.service);
        assertThat(this.service.toString()).containsOnlyDigits();
    }

    @Configuration
    static class MyConfig {

        @Bean
        public SomeService someService(@Value("${my.random.port}") int port) {
            return new SomeService(port);
        }
    }

    static class SomeService {
        private final int port;

        public SomeService(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(this.port);
        }
    }

    public static class RandomPortInitializer
            implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            int randomPort = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(applicationContext,
                    "my.random.port=" + randomPort);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This is how you can set properties during startup if you are running spring boot application.

The easiest way is to set the properties before you even started an app.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = new ConfigurableEnvironment();
        env.setActiveProfiles("whatever");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("server.port", 9999);
        env.getPropertySources()
            .addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("initProps", properties));

        application.setEnvironment(env);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, seems like my answer is very similar to the one provided by Roger Thomas.

Comment: Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the `put` and `putAll` methods can be applied to a `Properties` object. Their use is **strongly discouraged** as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or values are not Strings. The setProperty method should be used instead. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Answer (score 5):

With this Method in your configuration you can set default properties.

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class)
              .properties("propertyKey=propertyValue");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can override the application.properties programatically if you have to.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Restdemo1Application.class);
    app.setAdditionalProfiles("dev"); 
    // overrides "application.properties" with  "application-dev.properties"
    app.run(args);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add another option, there's a [BeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) class that you can implement. It provides two methods:

`postProcessAfterInitialization` and `postProcessBeforeInitialization`

> Factory hook that allows for custom modification of new bean instances — for example, checking for marker interfaces or wrapping beans with proxies.
> Typically, post-processors that populate beans via marker interfaces or the like will implement postProcessBeforeInitialization(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String), while post-processors that wrap beans with proxies will normally implement postProcessAfterInitialization(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String).

In my code example, I was using it to override Kafka Location properties, because for SSL it doesn't read from classpath.

So this was the code:

```
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClientConfig;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SslConfigs;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConfiguration implements BeanPostProcessor {

  @Value("${spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location:}")
  private Resource keyStoreResource;
  @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location:}")
  private Resource trustStoreResource;
  private final Environment environment;

  @SneakyThrows
  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof KafkaProperties) {
      KafkaProperties kafkaProperties = (KafkaProperties) bean;
      if(isLocalProfileActive()) {
        configureStoreLocation(kafkaProperties);
      }
    }
    return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);
  }

  private boolean isLocalProfileActive() {
    return Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch(profile -> "local".equals(profile));
  }

  private void configureStoreLocation(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) throws IOException {
    kafkaProperties.getSsl().setKeyStoreLocation(new FileSystemResource(keyStoreResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath()));
    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(SchemaRegistryClientConfig.CLIENT_NAMESPACE + SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, keyStoreResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
    kafkaProperties.getSsl().setTrustStoreLocation(new FileSystemResource(trustStoreResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath()));
    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(SchemaRegistryClientConfig.CLIENT_NAMESPACE + SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, trustStoreResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
  }

}
```

This way I could have on my properties file:

`spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=classpath:mykeystore.jks`

And the code would get the absolute path from that and set it. It makes also possible to filter based on profiles.

In your scenario, you would check probably for [DataSourceProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.html). It's important to mention that BeanPostProcessor runs for **EVERY** bean, so make sure you filter what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add string to your Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.location",
                "file:///D:/SpringProjects/SpringBootApp/application.properties");

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: If only life were this simple. This doesn't work for my convoluted eureka server spring boot setup. This is why I'd never inflict Spring on myself if the decisions were made by me.

Answer (score -1):

Under META-INF folder create exactly this folders and file:
spring>batch>override>data-source-context.xml
and in your xml file make sure to override the paramters you want like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${loader.jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${loader.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${loader.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${loader.jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

or use a jndi like this in the xml file to access your external configuration file like catalina.properties

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
    jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/loader-batch-dataSource" lookup-on-startup="true"
    resource-ref="true" cache="true" />
```