# spring boot/batch disable batch auto start via code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I'm writing a spring batch application consisting of different jobs who need to be executed in a specific order.
In order to do that I'm running the jobs manually through a JobLauncher, and I disabled the auto start feature provided by Spring batch by adding the following property in my properties file:

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

I would like to disable this feature directly in the code, instead of relying on a configuration file that can be accessed and modified by anyone.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you can try with JavaConfig

Comment: Does [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072628/how-to-override-spring-boot-application-properties-programmatically) by Roger Thomas help ? Idea is put to put hard coded value in code all the time.

Comment: Hi @SabirKhan, thanks for your reply. It is working but it can be bypassed by explicitly setting "spring.batch.job.enabled=true" in the property files. Better than nothing though.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.batch.job", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public JobLauncherCommandLineRunner jobLauncherCommandLineRunner(
        JobLauncher jobLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
    JobLauncherCommandLineRunner runner = new JobLauncherCommandLineRunner(
            jobLauncher, jobExplorer);
    String jobNames = this.properties.getJob().getNames();
    if (StringUtils.hasText(jobNames)) {
        runner.setJobNames(jobNames);
    }
    return runner;
}
```

This is from `BatchAutoConfiguration`.

Judging by this, you could try to add your own implementation of `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner` which does nothing. This will affect the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` and it shouldn't run.