# Is there a way to disable Spring batch job autostart without using spring.batch.job.enabled: false in application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to trigger a batch job using rest controller.Just need to know if there is any way to disable spring batch job autorun programatically without using application.properties file

Comment: Perhaps this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977933/spring-boot-batch-disable-batch-auto-start-via-code) is what you are looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring boot/batch disable batch auto start via code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977933/spring-boot-batch-disable-batch-auto-start-via-code)