# How to use selenium + phantomJs in spring boot?

Tags: java, selenium, spring-boot, phantomjs

I want to use selenium + phantomJs in my Spring boot project for scrapy. I can make it work in a normal java app like this :

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", path_to_phantomjs.exe);
PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.get(a_web_url);
WebElement e = driver.findElementByXPath("//button[@title='load-more']");
e.click();
JSWaiter.setDriver(driver);
JSWaiter.waitJsJQueryAngular();
String html = driver.getPageSource();
System.out.println(html);
driver.quit();
```

I set phantomJs in my spring boot project like this

```
main
|__java
|__resources
   |__static
      |__phantomJs
         |__pahntomjs.exe
```

Whether I call :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "static/phantomJs/phantomjs.exe");
    SpringApplication.run(PricecompareApplication.class, args);
}
```

or :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/crawl"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String crawlProduct(Model model, CrawlerOption crawlOption)
{
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "static/phantomJs/phantomjs.exe");
    PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(); // <-- always error at this
}
```

My program alway throw this error when i create a new PhantomJSDriver :

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.openqa.selenium.os.ExecutableFinder from class org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService
```

It seem like I set the wrong path or I can not access the resources, but when I use the path to phantomjs.exe in my console app (the first code block in my question), still the same error .

How can I config selenium + phantomjs in Spring boot?

Comment: Did you try with absolute url?
If yes, I would try setting the property to the spring boot app directly:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072628/how-to-override-spring-boot-application-properties-programmatically

Comment: Spring boot does not accept extend property, if i set `phantomjs.binary.path` in my `application.properties` , spring can not resolve it. According to [this issue](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/issues/561) , the problem is caused by gradle. I update my build.gradle and everything work fine.

Comment: Wow, interesting. I'm glad that it's solved :)