# How can I force SpringBoot to use One and only One of multiple config classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project that has two different runtimes in it (one a lambda and one a fargate).  I have two different configs but only want one to run.

[image]

How do I exclude and include config classes?  This didn't seem to work:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DynamoConfig.class)
```

And since they are in the same "path", I can't exclude just the package

```
com.cat.lakitu.runner
```

because the "persist" package will be excluded as well.

Comment: What about using Profiles ?

Comment: We are already using profiles but they are currently the same for both apps.  It would be very intrusive.

Comment: You can have multiple active profiles with Spring. Can you elaborate on how using a profile here would be "intrusive?"

Comment: We are currently in AWS with lots of build scripts and such.  This would include a rename of several fields and lots of fat fingering of files.  Would like something a bit less intrusive - in our use case.

Comment: What is the condition of using the first config or the second config ?

Comment: Well, both use a different "main" class in the app.  Can I ADD a profile programatically?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072628/how-to-override-spring-boot-application-properties-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the @ConditonalOnProperty annotation here on two configs, and add the properties in the main of one of the runtimes , take for example lambda  (since you said each run uses a different one)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("lambda.application", "true");
    application.setDefaultProperties(properties);
    application.run(args);
}
```

then on the config needed when run time is lambda you can annotate the bean as such

```
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
        value="lambda.application",
        havingValue = "true")
public class DyanmoConfig {
```

Then the other bean could have the following conditional properties

```
        @ConditionalOnProperty(
        value="lambda.application",
        havingValue = "false",
        matchIfMissing= true)
public class PersistConfig {
```

This way you only need to set the properties programatically in one of the two main's

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of solving this. Which one you choose depends on your specific use case and needs.

Using profiles: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Example:

```
@Component
@Profile("runtime1")
public class DynamoConfig
```

Using conditional beans (multiple possibilities): https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-conditionals/

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    value="module.enabled", 
    havingValue = "true", 
    matchIfMissing = true)
public class DynamoConfig
```

Comment: So we already use a "dev", "qa", "prod" profile.  But we need one more.  How do you set multiple?

Comment: If you are using a recent Spring Boot version you can add multiple profiles like this:
@Profile({"profile1 & profile2"})

Comment: I believe that is how you use them, not how you set them.  I may be wrong.

Comment: @markthegrea https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-profiles