# How to disable Rabbit health check via Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I would like to disable the rabbit health check in my default RabbitMockConfiguration.
We have a Configuration that is imported via `@Import`. Unfortunately the Configuration does not prevent the health check from being added to the health indicator as that happens once spring-rabbit is in the classpath.

We have the workaround, that we add a properties file in every service using that Configuration, which disables the property `management.health.rabbit.enabled`, but for us it would be much nicer to be able to disable that heathcheck on configuration level.

I thought about the tests with `@TestPropertySource(properties = ["management.health.rabbit.enabled=false"])`, but I could not find an equivalent to use for the a `@Configuration`, as `@PropertySource` expects a location for a properties file and does not accept single properties.

Any idea what we can do?

Spring boot version: 2.2.4
Spring amqp version: 2.2.3
Spring Version: 5.2.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the behaviour of the health check, I'd rather override the health check so that it states Rabbit is in mock mode.

To do so, just create a `HealthIndicator` bean named `rabbitHealthIndicator`:

```
@Bean
public HealthIndicator rabbitHealthIndicator() {
    return () -> Health.up().withDetail("version", "mock").build();
}
```

This has the effect of switching the production one and exposes the fact the app is running with a mock.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should add 'ApplicationListener' and add the implementation to 'src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories' to your module with MockReddisConfiguration. This is described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29133241/6075655)

Comment: wow that sounds very heavy :( is there nothing easier, like for Test the TestPropertySource

Comment: DoI understand right that you want to run the application with redis mock (e.g. for developing) and you manually add @Import(MockConfig) to your app? Maybe you are able to use some special profiles (e.g. "dev"), mark the configuration as @Profile("DEV") and add required properties to "DEV" section in application.yml, and run the app with "DEV' spring profile when need mock redis?

Comment: then again I would have to write this in the application.yml of every service, I would like to have it at the point where it is needed. Also a point of readability there as well as you have it all together instead of spread over files