# Is there any way to by default expose custom actuator endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Today if I want to expose my custom actuator endpoint I have to added below config in `application.properties`

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,myAwesomeActuator
```

```java
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "myAwesomeActuator")
public class MyAwesomeActuator {

    @ReadOperation
    public String test() {
        return "Hello, from MyAwesomeActuator";
    }
}
```

If I don't add above config Spring Boot by default expose only `/health` and `/info` endpoints

Is there any way where I can mark my actuator as by default exposed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done for security reasons. Some endpoints can be too "vulnerable" to be exposed in production.

For development, its possible to expose all the endpoints at once by putting

```
management.endpoint.web.exposure.include=*
```

Another option is analyzing the value of the property and adding your endpoints "programmatically" before the actuator actually starts.
There are many possible approaches here depending on spring boot version.

I've found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072628/how-can-i-override-spring-boot-application-properties-programmatically) that describes the options.

One interesting option is writing an environment post processor that will analyze the property and override with your custom value, in that SO thread this option is alread mentioned.

The example of how to work with properties in the environment post processor can be seen [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/48f3f9783f277a795d0210399f0ea09b7f1a4e71/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceEnvironmentPostProcessor.java) (again from that SO thread)