# How to set Hibernate TimeZone programmatically?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, timezone

I have `Spring Boot Data JPA` project running with `UTC` timezone. This project communicates with `MSSQL` database which runs with `CST` timezone.

Now I understand that if I want to instruct spring boot project to consider database timezone, I have below 2 options.

1. Change default TimeZone of `JVM` to `CST`; which I do not want as I want to keep Spring boot application's timezone as `UTC` only.
2. In `application.properties` file, set property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=America/Chicago` so that hibernate can convert date from `UTC` to `CST` whenever a record is inserted/updated/read from/to database.

Second option works great for me; however, I have a situation that underlying database could sooner be deployed on different datastore with another timezone. Hence I want to make the time zone property configurable (By configurable, I mean I will make this timezone as an environment variable, so that I no longer need `spring boot` app reboot).

Is there any way to set the property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` programmatically?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072628/how-can-i-override-spring-boot-application-properties-programmatically) will be helpful.

Comment: @SternK let me try it out

Comment: @SternK, above link looks okay if I want to override it once during application life cycle. Once my env variable is changed, how will it reflect as the property overload happens once only?

Comment: Is [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) something you're looking for?

Comment: There are several ways to programatically set that property. I found at least two of them described [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/23/spring-tips-configuration). I would favor the `contributeToTheEnvironment` method described, but that's a personal preference.