# Gzip compression in java Feign client builder in non declarative way

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm trying to make a rest call using feign.

How do I do a Gzip compression in Java using Feign client builder in non declarative way as I don't have *application.yml* to do it in traditional way.

Is there a way to using Encoder or Interceptor method of feign client builder to do the same?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation [Feign request/response compression](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#_feign_request_response_compression), we can enable GZIP for request and response by setting below properties:

```
feign.compression.request.enabled=true
feign.compression.response.enabled=true
```

Since you don't have `application.yml`(quite strange when you are using spring boot), we can set the programmatically by referring to [How can I override Spring Boot application.properties programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072628/how-can-i-override-spring-boot-application-properties-programmatically/#35817100).

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoFeignApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(DemoFeignApplication.class);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("feign.compression.request.enabled", "true");
        properties.put("feign.compression.response.enabled", "true");
        application.setDefaultProperties(properties);
        application.run(args);
        SpringApplication.run(DemoFeignApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: We are using a shared project across multiple teams for e2e test. I need to build a feign client with Gzip compression locally in my class. setting in application.yml applies globally which is restricted.

Comment: So are you trying to configure 1 specific class with `@FeignClient`? Can you provide some sample code in your post?