# Spring Boot build information via /info actuator endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-actuator

In a Spring Boot application, I would like to get the build and other application related information in `/info` actuator endpoint via `buildInfo()` from `springBoot` plugin task. However, the build information properties file name is not `build-info.properties` rather it's different `{app_name}.properties`. The property file exists in `/META-INF/{app_name}.properties` in the spring boot created fat jar.

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

My question is: Is there any way the property file name can be configured in the task rather than taking default?

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that with the above config when you run `bootBuildInfo` task it does not generate `build-info.properties` for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misinterpret how `buildInfo` works. `actuator` endpoint uses `build-info.properties` file from `/META-INF/`. `buildInfo` configuration does not work in runtime, actually there is no gradle at runtime (that is when your application runs for example on production).

`buildInfo()` adds a task to you gradle build that can generate `build-info.properties` based on properties in `{app_name}.properties` file during build of your application. Given that you already has it you need to run it during the build as described in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#integrating-with-actuator-build-info):

> This will configure a BuildInfo task named bootBuildInfo and, if it
>   exists, make the Java plugin’s classes task depend upon it

Comment: Thanks Roman. The `buildInfo()` task is creating the `build-info.properties` however, and the details is being retrieved in the `/info` end point. However, I am not seeing the properties in the fat jar META-INF folder, where as I am seeing the properties `*-processor-service.properties` in the jar. I am still researching that which task in the project is creating the same which has lot more build information than `build-info.properties`.I am wondering if there is any way I can get the information from `*-processor-service.properties` in the `/info` end point instead of `build-info.properties`.

Comment: I think you can using methods described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863972/how-do-i-add-things-to-the-info-endpoint-in-spring-boot-programmatically